# How to write "NULL" into CSV from Excel for blank fields

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, csv

How do I write "NULL" for blank fields when I export a CSV file from Excel 2007?  Is there a feature to do that?

Comment: Null meaning nothing there, or null meaning something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While exporting, i think it may not be possible.

But you can also try this way before saving or after saving

```
1. Click F5
2. Click Special
3. Select Blanks
4. Click OK
5. Type NULL
6. Press CTRL + Enter
```

OR

With macro, VB code:

```
Sheet1.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)="NULL"
```

Comment: Add a second line to the macro: 
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False  -- The macro will now search and replace with "NULL" and save the file, all in one step.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:  You don't do anything.

There is no difference between an Excel cell with an empty string or one with no value (null) for purposes of exporting a CSV.  The fields in CSV files don't actually have data types. So you will get an empty field in your CSV file either way.  Example:

[image]

Will generate a CSV that contains:

```
12,,54
```

Nothing between the two delimiters (commas) means empty or null.  How the empty value is dealt with depends on the software that is reading the CSV file.

Comment: My question was is there a way to write the word "NULL" for each empty field from Excel.

Comment: Sorry you didn't say that or you would have gotten a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

Open the CSV file in a text editor, such as Notepad, and do a find/replace all `,,` => `,NULL,`. It's not within Excel, but it will still work.

Comment: Just a warning: This doesn't handle quotes or cells at the beginning or end of each line. Also if there are multiple empty cells next to each other you have to do it twice.

Answer (score 1):

I know this works in newer Excel; not sure about the older version.

1. Select Cell `A1`; then shift click the most bottom right selection
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
3. In the "Find" field leave it blank
4. in the "Replace With" field put in `NULL`

This should replace all the nothings with 'NULL' in the selected cells.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know Excel but this python script will do it

```python
import csv,sys
fin = open(sys.argv[1],'rb')
fout = open(sys.argv[2],'wb')
reader = csv.reader(fin, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
writer = csv.writer(fout, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
for row in reader:
    new = []
    for s in row:
        if s=='':
            new.append('null')
        else:
            new.append(s)
    writer.writerow(new)
fin.close()
fout.close()
```

Comment: Your Python skills are commendable, but what does this have to do with the question that was asked?

Comment: It would solve the problem a different way. I just had that script laying around and though OP would find it useful.

Comment: This is helpful, btw. Shouldn't be downvoted.

Comment: Offtopic ? anyways, requires ***install Python in Windows*** (not _chocolatey_ )